# Can I enter password once for multiple mysql command line invocations, where the queries are not known upfront?

Tags: mysql

You can avoid re-entering mysql command line password by putting the queries into a file.

In my case, the later queries are not determined until after the first queries have finished.

This happens in a non-interactive script so running a mysql console is not an option.

Is there any notion of a session for mysql command line interactions? Or can I set it up to listen for commands on a local unix socket (the output is required to be returned)? Or something like that?

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but have you tried to have the user and password in a .my.cnf file (or using mysql-config-editor in newer versions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html)

Comment: You are now running at least one MySQL connection from a script you declare non-interactive. How is that one instance running? Just do the same with the subsequent connections. If that instance asks for a password, simply ask for the password *yourself* using `read` and store it in an environment variable. Then pass that to all the MySQL instances.

Comment: I suggest that the solution is shortsighted.  You may like calling `mysql` in a shell script now, but eventually you will see how clumsy it gets.  Then you will either send a list of SQL statements to `mysql` at once (with one pwd typing) or use a client that can talk to mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User @smcjones mentions using the .my.cnf file or mysql_config_editor. Those are good suggestions, I give my +1 vote to him.

Another solution is to put the credentials in any file of your choosing and then specify that file when you invoke MySQL tools:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=my_special.cnf ...other arguments...
```

And finally, just for completeness, you can use environment variables for some options, like host and password. But strangely, not the user. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html

```
export MYSQL_HOST="mydbserver"
export MYSQL_PWD="Xyzzy"
mysql ...other arguments...
```

I don't really recommend using an environment variable for the password, since anyone who can run `ps` on your client host can see the environment variables for the mysql client process.

---

Re comment regarding environment variables:

I accept that the truth on modern *Linux* is that [only the owner of the process can see their environment](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14009) using `ps` or `/proc/<pid>/environment`.

But it's also true that in BSD UNIX (including MacOS), `ps` works differently, and will show environment for other users.

Even on Linux, the fact that the user might inadvertently show their own environment in `ps` is enough of a reason to avoid using environment variables for sensitive information.

Regardless of operating system, the feature of using environment variables for passwords is deprecated.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html says:

> Use of `MYSQL_PWD` to specify a MySQL password must be considered extremely insecure and should not be used. Some versions of ps include an option to display the environment of running processes. On some systems, if you set `MYSQL_PWD`, your password is exposed to any other user who runs ps. Even on systems without such a version of ps, it is unwise to assume that there are no other methods by which users can examine process environments.
>
> `MYSQL_PWD` is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0; expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL.

Comment: I use the `--defaults-extra-file` approach. +10 .

Comment: The note about environment variables being available to anyone who can run ps is false - see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/environment-variable-accessibility-in-linux/14009#14009

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to handle this in MySQL.

1. Put password in hidden `.my.cnf` in the home directory of the user the script is running as.

   [client]
   user=USER
   password=PASSWORD
2. Use [`mysql_config_editor`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html)

   mysql_config_editor set --login-path=client --host=localhost
       --user=localuser --password

When prompted to enter your password, enter it like you otherwise would.

3. IMO this is the worst option, but I'll add it for the sake of completeness.

You could always create a function wrapper for MySQL that appends your set password.

```
#! /bin/bash

local_mysql_do_file() {
    mysql -u localuser -h localhost -pPASSWORD_NO_SPACE < $1
}

# usage
local_mysql_do_file file.sql
```

Comment: option 1a). include user, password and host lines (along with any other variable settings we want for our session), under the `[client]` section of a mysql options file. Then include the option file with the mysql execution...  `mysql --defaults-extra-file /opt/mysql/client1options.cnf`.  This approach lets us create multiple client configuration files,for different mysql users,.